# What do I lose access to by turning the Member Module off?

Tags: templates, members, conditionals

My sites tend to only have need for a few site admins and one or two super admins to maintain content. If I turn off the Member Module what do I lose access to from a template tag standpoint? What limits for using conditional logic to see who's logged in will I have? Anything else I might or might not be able to do?

Comment: Good question! I've never turned this module off myself. Curious to hear the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turning off the member module primarily affects people who do not have control panel access. You will not be able to create a login form on your site, or allow people to register themselves. Basically, you lose access to the {exp:member:...} template tags.

This can be useful to prevent database bloat from spammers who discover the "member" URL keyword (See Members -> Preferences -> Profile Triggering Word).

The EE docs list [three primary uses](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/member/index.html#introduction) of the Member module:

- The Members section, which hosts a comprehensive suite of member management utilities including the Membership Preferences page.
- The My Account Page, accessible from the Control Panel’s sidebar. It can also display information for any member if you choose a particular member from Members
- The public side of your website also has a Member Profile area, enabling your site members to manage their personal profile information without having access to your Control Panel.

If everyone who needs to log in is able to access the Control Panel, you should be able to disable the Member module without any side effects (except the middle one, which is of little consequence when all members are admins).

Comment: Interesting. I'll have to test the second option and see how bad the results really are. I create at a minimum a Site Admin member group and give them enough access to edit entries and things like categories but I lock out templates and other things like most add-ons. I've never really looked to see if they really need access to the member profile section. Can you leave the members trigger word blank so it can never be activated or is a random string the only way to obfuscate it?

Comment: I usually do something along the lines of `$config['profile_trigger'] = rand(0,time());` to randomize the trigger. I believe that FocusLab's Master Config file does something similar.

Comment: Justin, your config tweak is a fantastic idea. The field does require a value so we have typically hit a bunch of random keyboard characters.